# Calculate aggregates based on fields in BigQuery's repeated records

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

```
{
"outer_1": "1",
"outer_2": 2,
"inner": [
  {
    "inner_1": 0,
    "inner_2": null,
    },
  {
    "inner_1": 3,
    "inner_2": true,
  },
 ]
}
```

Above you can see roughly what my data looks like. In terms of BigQuery, `inner` is a repeated record. I would like to calculate aggregates (like the sum of non-null `inner_1` fields) for each row.

One idea is to use `unnest(inner)`, calculate aggregates and then group by all other columns. This doesn't seem, however, to be the optimal approach. I already have about a million rows. Unnesting would create tremendously many more rows and doing aggregation to group everything right away doesn't sound right.

I bet there might be a more efficient way to iterate over nested records and calculate aggregates for them.

In the end, I would like to have something like:

```
    {
"outer_1": "1",
"outer_2": 2,
"inner_1_sum: 3, 
"inner_2_non_null_count": 1
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select * except(inner_col),
  ( select as struct 
      sum(inner_1) as inner_1_sum,
      countif(not inner_2 is null) as inner_2_non_null_count
    from unnest(inner_col)
  ).*
from `project.dataset.table`
```

If applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I was trying to achieve. I just noticed that using `select as struct` and `select struct` (with additional parentheses) yields similar results except for naming. The documentation doesn't seem to mention the differences explicitly, can you please briefly elaborate on that a bit?

Comment: you can use `struct<name1 TYPE1, name2 TYPE2>(value1, value2)` to identify the column names you wish. In your case above it can be `select struct<inner_1_sum INT64, inner_2_non_null_count INT64>(sum(inner_1), countif(not inner_2 is null)) from unnest(inner_col)`. Meantime, glad it worked for you, consider also voting up the answer if not yet :o)

Comment: I have upvoted and accepted your answer ;-) 

Surprisingly, `select struct(sum(inner_1) as inner_1_sum, countif(not inner_2 is null) as inner_2_non_null_count)` also works as desired. Is that correct?

Comment: yes. no surprises. this notion for struct also documented and works :o)

Comment: Thank you so much! The flexibility of BigQuery and what it allows you to do is truly impressive :)